# Are these two expressions for sums of binomial coefficients valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

These two appear in my module (without any proof):

$$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} C(n-2,r-2) = 2^{n-1}$$

$$\sum_{r = 0}^{n-1} C(n-2,r) = 2^{n-2}$$

For the first one when when $r=1 \Rightarrow  C(n-2,1-2) =  C(n-2,-1)$ ?!The same thing for $r=n-1$ in the second one,are they valid if yes,please explain how?

Comment: Are those binomial coefficients?

Comment: Yes.Yes.Yes.Yes.

Comment: If those are indeed binomial coefficients, the RHS for both ought to be $2^{n-2}$. In any event, the [binomial theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html) is of use here.

Comment: Nopes in my module it's given that only the second is $n-2$.

Comment: Not gettin J.M could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Let's take the case $n=3$ as an example.  The first summation claims that $C(1,-1)+C(1,0)+C(1,1) = 2^2$.  Conventionally $C(1,-1)$ is zero, so the claim is incorrect.  Similarly the second summation claims $C(1,0)+C(1,1)+C(1,2) = 2^2$, and since $C(1,2)$ is zero by convention, is similarly incorrect.  Perhaps something was omitted in the text?

Comment: $$\sum_{r=1}^n \binom{n-2}{r-2}=\sum_{r=2}^n \binom{n-2}{r-2}=\sum_{r+2=2}^{r+2=n} \binom{n-2}{r+2-2}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \binom{n-2}{r}$$

Comment: @hardmath:Thanks I was missing that part only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Use the binomial expansion for $(1+x)^{n-2}$ and choose an appropriate value for $x$. Binomial coefficients with a negative value of $r$ are zero. You should see what the LHS ought to be.

Comment: The LHS is same as I mentioned that's creating some confusion in my mind.

Comment: @Debanjan: No, I meant what the LHS should equal as a power of $2$.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the calculation implied by Timothy's answer, let me describe a way to see it directly.  Consider $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}C(n-2,r)$.  This is the sum of

(the number of ways of choosing a subset of $0$ elements out of a set of $n-2$ elements)

+ (the number of ways of choosing a subset of $1$ element out of a set of $n-2$ elements)

+ (the number of ways of choosing a subset of $2$ elements out of a set of $n-2$ elements)

. . . 
+ (the number of ways of choosing a subset of $n-1$ elements out of a set of $n-2$ elements)

Since any subset of $n-2$ elements has either 0, 1, 2, . . . , or $n-2$ elements, the total is just the number of ways of choosing *any* subset of $n-2$ elements.  And this is just $2^{n-2}$.